# How can I get the name of my app reliably from the Facebook Marketing Api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-insights

I am trying to retrieve my app campaigns and their associated apps with their events via my advertiser account.

The problem is that I am unable to find a unique identifier for my app in the API response.

For example the query below will get me the 'action_target_id'. This would either equal my AppId or another numeric string which I don't know what is. I am confused, does it mean I have two AppIds?

```
act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/reportstats?time_interval={"day_start":{"day":"01","month":"03","year":"2014"},"day_stop":{"day":"07","month":"04","year":"2015"}}&data_columns=['adgroup_id', 'actions','action_target_id','action_target_name','campaign_name']&actions_group_by=['action_device','action_type']&format=json&async=true
```

**What are 'action_target_id' and 'action_target_name' meant to represent (in the context of running a campaign for a mobile app)?** I cannot seem to find a clear explanation for this in the API doc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [applications/developer edge](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/applications/developer) will return applications your account has access to.

As for your second question, the action_target_id and action_target_name are not always your application. It depends on what the action specs of each campaign is, if even set. An 'action spec' is a FB format for defining relationships between an ad and various objects for various purposes. More about that at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/intro-action-specs

In your case, the action spec in the context of a mobile app ad campaign will probably be the FB application. See also [default conversion spec](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversion-specs/v2.2#default) and [default tracking spec](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/tracking-specs/v2.2).